# Store VBA calculate Values in Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Respected Experts, I want to store each value in VBA-Array which is calculated by VBA Loop. after the looping is Done I would like to use that VBA-Array for my further Calculations.Below example explain my question more specifically.

```
Sub macro3()

For x = 1 To 5
xx = 1 + x
Next

End Sub
```

Basically the each Answer which derived i.e.(2,3,4,5,6) from above loop has to be stored in Particular Array OR in something which help me out to use each value's i.e.(2,3,4,5,6) again for my further calculations.The whole activity has to be done from VBA memory Only.Basically i don't want to use Excel Spreadsheet range to store the each Loop Value and then define that spreadsheet range as Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of elements, then the following would create an array called 'answer' (see DIM statement) that holds the five evaluations:

```
Sub macro3()

Dim answer(1 To 5)
For x = 1 To 5
    answer(x) = 1 + x
Next

End Sub
```

I suspect though that what you're after might be a little more complicated than that, so give more detail if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you so much Both the expert's.The above given both logic's are resolved my concern.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CLR's answer - if you dont' know the number of elements the basic formula to ReDim the array would look something like this -

```
Sub macro3()
Dim x As Integer
Dim xx() As Variant

For x = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve xx(0 To x - 1)
    xx(x - 1) = 1 + x
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I would try to avoid the 'ReDim Preserve' part in the For-Loop. it seriously increases the calculation time.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost depends so much on what kind of situation. What you are talking is about optimization with large amounts of data, but with under 10k records it doesn't matter much. The best of course is if you can define large enough array in the very beginning and limit ReDims for example every 10k records.

Comment: i don't see the benefit in resizing an array in each iteration, if you know the length beforehand. If you have an array, where the length changes in some iterations, I agree with your approach.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost lol, this must be the me still hanging on to the memory limitations when I was a young coder (Amiga, 386 etc). The ReDim comes handy if you have smaller amount amounts of records or if you want to conserve RAM memory. The fact is nowadays computers have RAM quite enough to easily hand millions of records, that was not the the case 20 years ago. Still there are times you still want to use ReDim, my answer is yet only a very rough sample of basic functionality rather than a model for real life usage.

Comment: Further to my question is it possible to Link some other Data Array with my current array i.e.**answer** and develop one **Table** in VBA memory.Again I don't want to use Excel Spreadsheet. for example if I link other data Array which also contain same number of 5 elements(A,A,B,C,C) and I want to link the same with array **answer** and develop the Table. if such creation of table possibility is exist will I able to apply the formula like sumif on that developed Table.

Comment: @sagar basically yes and no. Storing data over multiple runs is where VBA fails you and you will need to store the data somewhere. For that matters, I'm not sure if I understand your question fully but I find it hard to understand why would you want to do so and why using excel sheet to store data is such a bad option..

Comment: Sir Actually I have huge data and in every step to summaries it i will have to create number of tables which result into number sheet in my workbook thus I am trying to create table in VBA memory only and only for final summary i would like to use spreadsheet.

Comment: @sagar Yes that can be done, it's not hard but I would suggest thinking what is the most efficient way. Sometimes the many many sheets doing calculation is actually the more effective than building from scratch with VBA. It also depends how massive operations there are done within the code. We are tho getting out of scope of this original question. Classes in VBA are quite nifty for doing such operations.